# Update annotation's subtitle

Tags: ios, xcode, annotations, android-mapview

I'm struggling with setting the subtitle of an annotation in MapView, once it has been clicked.

.m:

```
MKCoordinateRegion England = { {0.0, 0.0} , {0.0, 0.0} };
England.center.latitude = 51.50063;
England.center.longitude = -0.124629;
England.span.longitudeDelta = 100.0f;
England.span.latitudeDelta = 100.0f;
[mapView setRegion:England animated:YES];

Annotation *ann1 = [[Annotation alloc] init];
ann1.title = @"England";
ann1.subtitle = @"subtitle";
ann1.coordinate = England.center;
[mapView addAnnotation:ann1];


-(MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation: (id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {

MKPinAnnotationView *MyPin = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation  reuseIdentifier:@"current"]; MyPin.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;

UIButton *advertButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
[advertButton addTarget:self action:@selector(button:)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


MyPin.rightCalloutAccessoryView = advertButton;
MyPin.draggable = NO;
MyPin.highlighted = YES;
MyPin.animatesDrop = TRUE;
MyPin.canShowCallout = YES;

return MyPin;


}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView1 didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
{
id<MKAnnotation> selectedAnn = [mapView.selectedAnnotations objectAtIndex:0];
country_title = selectedAnn.title;

selectedAnn.subtitle = @"NEW SUBTITLE";

}
```

How do I set the subtitle once the annotation has been clicked? I wan't to do it that way, because I get some rows from mysql when it's clicked.. but I don't know how to update the subtitle for the specific annotation?

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    id<MKAnnotation> selectedAnn = view.annotation;
[mapview removeAnnotation:selectedAnn];

.. Add Annotation with new subtitle

[mapview addAnnotation:newselectedAnn];
[newselectedAnn setSelected:Yes animated:No];
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi Mohith! Thanks for your quick reply. Unfortunately I'm puzzled where to put in that line? I already have it in my didSelectAnnotationView: id<MKAnnotation> selectedAnn = [mapView.selectedAnnotations objectAtIndex:0];... I'm very new at this :(

Comment: Replace the entire contents with my snippet

Comment: I tried you snippet, but it only lets me put a new annotation a specific place. What if it's not the annotation I clicked? You can't just set a NSString property and then say:     id<MKAnnotation> selectedAnn = view.annotation;
    country_title = selectedAnn.title;
    
    if ([country_title isEqualToString:@"USA"]) {
        subtitle_USA = @"NEW SUBTITLE";
    }